# write & open pdf file using jspdf library in phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, jspdf

I have gone through many blogs, i have success to create pdf file in phonegap but with no data.

My Code
javascrpit :

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", createPDF, false);

function createPDF(){
var doc = new jsPDF();

doc.text(20, 20, 'HELLO!');

doc.setFont("courier");
doc.setFontType("normal");
doc.text(20, 30, 'This is a PDF document generated using JSPDF.');
doc.text(20, 50, 'YES, Inside of PhoneGap!');

//FIRST GENERATE THE PDF DOCUMENT
console.log("generating pdf...");
var doc = new jsPDF();

doc.text(20, 20, 'HELLO!');

doc.setFont("courier");
doc.setFontType("normal");
doc.text(20, 30, 'This is a PDF document generated using JSPDF.');
doc.text(20, 50, 'YES, Inside of PhoneGap!');

var pdfOutput = doc.output();
console.log( pdfOutput );

//NEXT SAVE IT TO THE DEVICE'S LOCAL FILE SYSTEM
console.log("file system...");
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {

   console.log("------------------------------------"+fileSystem.name);
   console.log("------------------------------------"+fileSystem.root.name);
   console.log("------------------------------------"+fileSystem.root.fullPath);

   fileSystem.root.getFile("test erp.pdf", {create: true}, function(entry) {
      var fileEntry = entry;
      console.log(entry);

      entry.createWriter(function(writer) {
         writer.onwrite = function(evt) {
         console.log("write success");
      };

      console.log("writing to file");
         writer.write( pdfOutput );
      }, function(error) {
         console.log(error);
      });

   }, function(error){
      console.log(error);
   });
},
function(event){
 console.log( evt.target.error.code );
});
}
```

and config.xml :

```
<plugin name="LocalFileSystem" value="org.apache.cordova.file"/>
```

and added only one javascrpit at the bottom of body

```
<script src="js/html_to_pdf/jspdf.source.js"></script>
```

If you try this, Then there will be no error on console and new file will be created on phone memory but as empty file and you will not be able to open it as dialog will  comes "Document size is 0".

Can anyone have any reference or solution on this.
Waiting for valuable reply.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i tried using the async file API. It generated some pdf though I could not manage to setup file encoding

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, 
    // onRequestFileSystemReady
    function(fileSystem) 
    {
        fileSystem.root.getFile("my.pdf",  
            {create : true},
            // onGetFileReady
            function(entry)
            {
                // entry is a "file entry"
                entry.createWriter(
                    // onWriterReady
                    function(writer) 
                    {
                        writer.onwrite = function(evt) {
                            console.log("write success");
                        };

                        console.log("writing to file");                                 
                        writer.onerror= onWriteError;
                        var blobBuilderError= false;
                        window.BlobBuilder = window.BlobBuilder ||
                                            window.WebKitBlobBuilder ||
                                            window.MozBlobBuilder ||
                                            window.MSBlobBuilder;
                        if ( typeof window.BlobBuilder === "undefined") 
                        {
                            console.error("BlobBuilder, not defined");      
                            blobBuilderError= true;
                        }


                        if(blobBuilderError !== true)                               
                        {
                         // it works with android not with ios 
                            var bb = new BlobBuilder(),
                                blob;
                            bb.append(PdfOutput);                   
                            blob = bb.getBlob("text/plain");
                            writer.write(blob);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            writer.write(PdfOutput); 
                        }                               
                    },                              
                    onWriterError
                );
            },
            onGetFileError
        );
    },              
    onRequestFileSystemError
);
```

onWriteError, onWriterError, onGetFileError, onRequestFileSystemError are error handlers doing what they shoudl do